# list files php from - create json file

Tags: php, json

I want to create a php script that loads all my files (.pdf) from the 3 directory and create a json file.

I try this

```
$dir_2016 = "./HCL/2016";
$dir_2015 = "./HCL/2015";
$dir_2014 = "./HCL/2014";

$files_2016 = array();
$files_2015 = array();
$files_2014 = array();

$json_file = array(
    "2016" => $files_2016,
    "2015" => $files_2015,
    "2014" => $files_2014
);  

if(is_dir($dir_2016) and is_dir($dir_2015) and is_dir($dir_2014))
{
    // 2016
    if(is_dir($dir_2016))
    {
        if($dh = opendir($dir_2016))
        {
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false)
            {
                if($file == "." or $file == ".."){

                } else {
                    $files_2016[] = $file; // Add the file to the array
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // 2015
    if(is_dir($dir_2015))
    {
        if($dh = opendir($dir_2015))
        {
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false)
            {
                if($file == "." or $file == ".."){

                } else {
                    $files_2015[] = $file; // Add the file to the array
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // 2014
    if(is_dir($dir_2014))
    {
        if($dh = opendir($dir_2014))
        {
            while(($file = readdir($dh)) != false)
            {
                if($file == "." or $file == ".."){

                } else {
                    $files_2014[] = $file; // Add the file to the array
                }
            }
        }
    }       
    echo json_encode($json_file);
}
```

but the output is:

```
{"2016":[],"2015":[],"2014":[]}
```

The files_2014[], files_2015[], files_2016[] are empty.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: move your definition of $json_file to the bottom. at the point where you assign $files_2016, that variable is *empty*. you have to fill it before you insert it.

Comment: Move this `$json_file = array(
    "2016" => $files_2016,
    "2015" => $files_2015,
    "2014" => $files_2014
);  ` after all of your loops

Comment: Have you considered refactoring your code? It's really repetitive. Something like https://3v4l.org/DqJAf would work just as well.

Comment: I think this counts as a TYPO and should be closed as such

Comment: @RiggsFolly Or it's a misunderstanding of how arrays work in php. E.g. `"2016" => &$files_2016,` would work, even though it's not obvious to a beginner.

Comment: @Yoshi yeah, and that shouldn't really be thought to a beginner since it *will* result in a lot more confusion later on.

Comment: My mistake, i have to move ot down
 $json_file = array(
    "2016" => $files_2016,
    "2015" => $files_2015,
    "2014" => $files_2014
   );   
  echo json_encode($json_file);
Using @Yoshi refactoring is much clean but i get on every file the name of the folder .\/HCL\/2016\/filename.pdf

Comment: @CălinBobeș just use `glob($dir . '/*.pdf');` if you only want those files. Here's the manual https://secure.php.net/manual/function.glob.php

Comment: @FranzGleichmann That may be so. My point is that it could work if php would handle arrays differently, e.g. as in javascript. And from the question we really can't tell whether it's a misconception (as in deliberate) or simply *not knowing*.

Comment: Maybe i didn`t make myself clear.  :) In each folder are only pdf files. Using the glob now, in each array (files_2014, etc) appear the path. I dont want the path to be in my json, only the file names. That was trying to say @Yoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on my comment above, here's a *cheap* way to get only pdf-filenames in the given directories:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset="utf-8"');

$dirs = [
    './HCL/2016',
    './HCL/2015',
    './HCL/2014',
];

$files = [];

foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        $files[basename($dir)] = glob($dir . '/*.pdf');
    }
}

array_walk_recursive($files, function (&$entry) {
    $entry = basename($entry);
});

echo json_encode($files, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

*Note that there's a multitude of other ways of how to get all files in a directory, so this is by no means the only solution.*

Answer (score 1):

You should move your definition of `$json_file` to bottom as follow:

```
// ... get files code
$json_file = array(
    "2016" => $files_2016,
    "2015" => $files_2015,
    "2014" => $files_2014,
);
echo json_encode($json_file);
```

Because `array` is `passing by value` rather than `passing by reference`.

And, a better way to get files and sub-directories in a directory shallowly is use `scandir`, for example:

```
$files_2014 = array_slice(scandir('./HCL/files_2014'), 2)
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php